# Do airlines of other Schengen countries share PNR data with a Schengen country?

Tags: schengen, international-travel, residency

Let me give an example.

You are a resident of Greece.

You fly with a Dutch airline from Belgium to (or from) Serbia.

1. Would Greece know about that flight?
2. Would Greece know about that flight after you apply for a permanent residence or equivalent? Maybe they look into all flight records to determine how many days you spent in Greece assuming they care about that stuff.
3. If you flew to/from Germany instead of Serbia, would the answers to my questions change?

Comment: Probably safest to assume the answer is “yes, if they wanted to look”  https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/law-enforcement-cooperation/passenger-data_en